# error = "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addUnique'\n at main.js:33:12"; Cloud code parse.com

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm sure the answer to this one is quite simple but I couldn't figure it out...

Here is my code in Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("acceptFriendRequest", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query("_User");
  var userFrom = new Parse.User();
  userFrom = query.get(request.params.userFrom);
  console.log(userFrom);

  var userTo = new String();
  userTo = request.params.userTo;

  userFrom.addUnique("friend", userTo);
  user.save().then(function (user) {
        response.success();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
   });

  response.success();
});
```

and here is my code in iOS:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"acceptFriendRequest"
                       withParameters:@{@"userFrom":userFrom.objectId,
                                        @"userTo":[PFUser currentUser].objectId}
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                                    }
                                }];
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
error = "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addUnique'\n    at main.js:33:12";
```

I also tried just the plain `userFrom.add()` method but it came with the same error!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your need to rewrite the cloud code. Whats the data type of `userFrom` and `userTo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for get to return the object.  I believe `get()` by itself is just returning null.

```
query.get(request.params.userFrom, {
  success: function(object) {
    userFrom = object;
    userFrom.addUnique("friend", userTo);
    user.save();
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // something went wrong
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Those sdk methods return promises, and the pointer columns must be populated with objects, not ids which is what you must be passing.  So you need to get both users and chain the asynch calls like this...

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var userFrom;  // so it's available in the second 'then' closure

Parse.Query(Parse.User).get(request.params.userFrom).then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
    userFrom = user;
    return Parse.Query(Parse.User).get(request.params.userTo);
}).then(function(userTo) {
    userFrom.addUnique("friend", userTo);
    return userFrom.save();
}).then(function (user) {
    response.success(user);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.error(error);
});
```